# Compiling against Crypto++ provided by Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, crypto++

I tried to install Crypto++ using apt-get: `sudo apt-get install libcrypto++-dev libcrypto++-doc libcrypto++-utils`. And then I tried to compile very simple program like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aes.h"
#include "modes.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main()
{
    cout << "Yo, man!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It resulted in ***`fatal error: aes.h: No such file or directory`***.

I'm a new Ubuntu user (Windows before), so I've done some research, but most people say that typing that one command is enough to get repository with Crypto++ library and make it work. Well, it is not in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you installed the library as you said (using `apt-get`), then try this:

```
#include <crypto++/aes.h>
#include <crypto/modes.h>
```

Instead of this:

```
#include "aes.h"
#include "modes.h"
```

You should use the `#include <crypto++/...>` because Ubuntu installs them in its "system", which means the preprocessor will look in particular places in a particular order when processing them. Also see [What is the difference between #include  and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593).

Also note that on Fedora and Red Hat, you would use `#include <cryptopp/...>`, not `#include <crypto++/...>`. If you are targeting multiple operating systems for Crypto++, then see [How to change the include file path with autotools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32805772).

Answer (score 0):

make sure to also include the `-lcryptopp` flag for the compilation command!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).