# How to change the include file path with autotools?

Tags: autotools, crypto++

I am developing a simple chat application, which use crypto++, in ubuntu. The folder for crypto++'s header files is `/usr/include/crypto++/`.

After I upload the source tagbar to `CentOS`, I found that the folder for crypto++'s header files is `/usr/include/cryptopp`. So in `CentOS`, the compiler could not find the head files for `cryptopp`.

Source File:

```
#include "crypto++/md5.h"
```

Configure.ac:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([_ZTIN8CryptoPP14CBC_EncryptionE], [crypto++ cryptopp], 
        [],[AC_MSG_ERROR([avchat requires crypto++/cryptopp])])
```

How to make the source bundle portable both on ubuntu and centos?

Comment: Oh yeah, that is an interesting little issue. I was always aware of the naming differences, but I never really thought about how to solve it. Maybe [symlink](http://stackoverflow.com/q/910433) the `cryptopp` directory as `crypto++` (or vice-versa)? (I try to avoid anything Autotools related because it usually results in confusing me).

Comment: @jww: Thx, i have made symbol link, it works. But i wondering if there is any standard solution?

Comment: *"... if there is any standard solution"* - well, "standard" can be fast and loose at times. Have you looked at using one of those [`pkg-config`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) files that distros provide?

Comment: Not sure if it matters ... I checked the `CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption` test by running `_ZTIN8CryptoPP14CBC_EncryptionE` though `c++filt`. It succeeded on Debian 8, but not OS X 10.8.5 and OS X 10.5.

Comment: I haven't test it OS X, thanks for your information.

Comment: We opened an issue for this at [Issue 36: Crypto++ should provide a pkg-config for users and distros](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/36). I've reached out to the Debian, Fedora and Macport maintainers to provide us with advice.